# how to get (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm") in silverlight which was embedded in html/javascript showModalDialog

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Hi  In CRM2011 I created custom button in form. On click of that button it opens javascript modal dialog. This modal dialog calls html where silverlight app is embedded. So my question i s how can I get following information. If silverlight app is in form we may easily get following values but my silver light app opens in modal dialog.

```
var xrmProperty = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm");
```

Comment: How is the dialog implemented, a new page? or more akin to a jQuery dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You want to talk to the opener.  For example, in JavaScript you'd call:

```
window.opener.Xrm.Page.getAttribute('cei_name').getValue()
```

to get the value of the "cei_name" attribute on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code

```
dynamic xrmnew = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm");
if (xrmnew == null)
{
    HtmlWindow parentWindow = HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("parent") as HtmlWindow;
    xrmnew = (ScriptObject)parentWindow.GetProperty("Xrm");
}
Guid Id = new Guid(xrmnew.Page.data.entity.getId());
```